# What is the best way to communicate between many gameObjects of same type in a state machine pattern in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to 2 or more objects involve in a state machine could communicate in the same state:

I'm trying to implement a risk-like game. My game environment is a map representation with different sections of the map represented as Territory(GameObject). I want two territories to be able to communicate between each other during an attacking move.

I have tried to employ the state machine technique to represent the different states a territory could be in, but because I have many of this objects to manage at once, I have just been able to switch between different states for different objects. I haven't been able to make 2 objects be aware of each other in the attacking phase.

What ways could I be able to make two objects communicate when an attack is taking placing between objects.

```
public class Territory: MonoBehaviour
{
    public TerritoryBaseState currentState;

    public void TransitionToState(TerritoryBaseState state)
    {
        currentState = state;
        StartCoroutine(currentState.EnterState());
    }
        private void Start(){
           TransitionToState(new TerritoryIdleState(this));
        }
        Private void Update(){
           currentState.Update(this);
        }
    
   }
```

A territory goes from Idle State -> Planning Phase State -> Attack State -> Execution State.

The but creeps in the attack phase when I need to objects in memory.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question ... what is your exact usecase? In general I think you could have a static collection of all instances of this script and then filter by state .. would this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Players or UI make moves in Risk not territories.

Territories have an owner, armies(count) and neighbors. All variables.

Players go through the states:

`{Idle State -> Planning Phase State -> Attack State-> Fortify State -> Idle State(delay until next turn)}`

Other players or UI are in the Idle State until next turn.